# C# MS Access Database Update with Dynamic Column Name

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ms-access, oledbconnection

I am trying to push data into a column where the name is a variable.

From the code below:
label1.Text is the dynamic column of the DB database (it is a string)

ComboBox1.Text is the data that I want to put into the dynamic column (column name = label1.Text)

```
connection.Open();
OleDBCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.ConnectionText = "update DB set column1='" + richTextBox1.Text + "', " + label1.Text + " = '" + comboBox1.Text + "' where ID=" + label2.Text;

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

I have tried many different things such as moving the single quotes and double quote locations, add the & sign for the string concatenation.  But all I have been able to do is push the label1.Text, ComboBox1.Text, and richTextBox1.Text all into column1...

This is only a small portion of my code, so please let me know if you have questions.

Comment: As long as table actually has field named for the variable value, should work. However, if field names have space or special character, need to delimit with `[ ]` characters.

Comment: Please show your code as it is. I don't think DB is your actual table name, so I don't think this is the statement that you use to update your table.

Comment: You had better to use parameters instead of strings concatenation due to security reasons [sql injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Here is an insert example with parameters: http://csharpexamples.com/selectinsertupdatedelete-data-in-access-file-using-c/

Comment: Thanks June7 there was a space in my column name sot he [ ] worked perfectly!